# Characteristics of melanin based semiconductors built from polydopamine

Tags: visible-light, semiconductor-physics, electrochemistry

I am curious to know if the relatively newly developed melanin-based semiconductor materials made with polydopachrome have been able to create films or crystals which visually reflect blue, purple or green hues (translated in to nm). If so, was the form of synthesized polydopachrome utilized in creating those outcomes more resembling that found in in the plant/fungi or more represententative of those found in the animal/insect kingdoms?

If blues, greens and purple light reflecting melanin based semiconductors exist, are the structures associated with concentrated or unusual copper bonds? Zinc? Manganese?